# Export email list parse for newsletter

Tags: parse-platform

How do I export the user emails from the database in a fast and easy way. I want the emails in a list so I can send out news letters. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a button in the data browser to export data. I believe this goes to a .CSV file, so you can delete the other columns and then just use a batch email sender to send your newsletter.

OR

Create a program that queries the _User table and takes the email column and creates a .csv file.

Comment: Yes. I done that. But how to I extract the emails from the data base? By hand? :=)

Comment: @user3615707 what do you mean extract the emails? From parse?

Comment: I can extract the data(all information) but I only want the signup emails. As it is now I have to copy paste them out from the data. Thanks for helping

Comment: Write a program that queries the user table and saves the emails to a csv file.

Comment: Thanks! I actually been thinking of building that. Best answer!